# how to get final select values using ajax jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

For example, if user select 1 first, and then he find that he doesn't need to select 1. So, he turn to select 2 and 3 then, but my code will output 1,2 and 3. What I want is only 2 and 3

my code below:

```
   <div class="column1">
        <h4>Column1</h4>
    <div class="box">
        <input type="radio" id="option1" name="cal" value="0" style="display:none" <?php if($mobile['cal'] == 0) { echo "checked"; }?>
        <label for="option1" >Disabled</label>
        <input type="radio" id="option2" name="cal" value="1" style="display:none" <?php if($mobile['cal'] == 1) { echo "checked"; }?>
        <label for="option2" >Enabled</label>
        <input type="radio" id="option3" name="cal" value="2"style="display:none" <?php if($mobile['cal'] == 2) { echo "checked"; }?>
        <label for="option3" >Read only</label>

    </div>
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please share the code you use

Comment: Hi I just shared the code :)

Comment: Hey @redbull you'll need to give the JS code as well please.